# Blazor Server Webapi Not working on postman

Tags: postman, blazor, webapi

I build the Blazor with template Blazor Server, Webassembly, Shared. It is working okay.

But when I try to test with postman. It always show this

[image]

the below is my testing controller. i can use blazor httpclient to access rest. but i want to test with postmna

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SchoolHero.Server.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SchoolHero.Server.Controllers.V1
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class BuggyController : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public BuggyController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("testauth")]
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult<string> GetSecretStuff()
        {
            return "super secret";
        }

        [HttpGet("notfound")]
        public ActionResult GetNotFoundRequest()
        {
            var thing = _context.Developers.Find(46);

            if (thing == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet("servererror")]
        public ActionResult GetServerError()
        {
            var thing = _context.Developers.Find(46);

            var thingToReturn = thing.ToString();

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet("badrequest")]
        public ActionResult GetBadRequest()
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        [HttpGet("badrequest/{id}")]
        public ActionResult GetNotFoundWithId(int id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

/// This is the startup class. I register. Seemd fine

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder; using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting; using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy; using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression; using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting; using SchoolHero.Server.Extensions; using System.Linq; using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SchoolHero.Server {
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddContextInfrastructure(_configuration);
            services.AddEssentials();
            services.AddIdentityService(_configuration);
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.ConfigureSwagger();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.Map("api/{**slug}", HandleApiFallback);
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }

        private Task HandleApiFallback(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    } }
```

Answer (score 1):

No code at all?
All I can say from that is that appears like you're sitting on an authentication loop.

Comment: i added some code on startup and api controller

Comment: there is no route i configure to account/login

Comment: You didn't but you specify authentication: `app.UseAuthentication();`